# Can a Progressive Web App (PWA) make REST requests to the user's `localhost`?

Tags: javascript, ajax, progressive-web-apps

Assuming the user is running a server ar `localhost:8080` for instance. Could my PWA issue a REST request to that server?

Comment: PWA's do not have any restrictions on web requests that normal websites do not have.

Comment: This is also one of those "try it and find out" questions, that you could self answer yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. In the simplest scenario, the user would have to provide you an IP Address (or a domain that points to that IP) and have port 8080 open.